# Embedded List ordering

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following object with an embedded list of items and I would like to write a query and return all or specific items ordered by `date`. Is it possible to do it or should I have a different collection for items and keep here their references?

I know that you can match specific element using `$elemMatch`.

```
{
  "_id": "51cb12857124a215940cf2d4",
  "level1":
    [
            {
                    "name":"item00",
                    "description":"item01",
                    "date": 1238492103
            },
            {
                    "name":"item10",
                    "description":"item11",
                    "date": 1238492104
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these items ordered by date on a more often than not then your best option is to keep the list ordered in the first place. The [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator has an additional [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) paramter explicitly for this purpose.

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": "51cb12857124a215940cf2d4" },
    { "$push": {
        "level1":{
            "$each":[{
                "name":"item11",
                "description":"item11",
                "date": 1238492104
            }],
            "$sort": { "date": 1 }
        }
    }
)
```

That actually even adapts so you could just sort your whole collection in one statement:

```js
db.collection.update(
    {},
    { "$push": {
        "level1":{
            "$each":[], "$sort": { "date": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

Without that your ony alternate is to order the results via the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. This really should not be your chosen operation as it requires processing [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array contents and then [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operation on the elements within the document. Naturally this comes with some significant overhead on larger selections:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$level1" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "level1.date": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "level1": { "$push": "$level1" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Will the $sort work for any list? for example 3rd level nested objects as well?

Comment: @glarkou Not sure what you are asking. Your document contains a single array which is all that is being dealt with here. If your documents are different from how you display in your question then you should ask another question. But if you have many arrays then the same principles apply, it's just than you need a little different handling.

Comment: Yes the question is: What if I have another array inside the array I already have in my example? Should the same principle with $sort work?

Comment: @glarkou That is an entirely different question, with different approaches again. I suggest you [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).